# Running White UI from Java

Tags: white-framework

Is there any way I can invoke White UI Automation tool from Java?
I already have a Java framework with me and now I need to handle some Silverlight application (which is legacy code and the developer has not made it scriptable). I don't want to maintain a separate workspace/technology for this. Is there any way I can call White UI or the underlying Windows UI Automation from within my Java code?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps IKVM would work? I haven't used it before, but it looks like it allows you to run Java code that can directly access .NET assemblies.

So, sounds like it might be a way to use both White and your Java test framework at the same time.

There's an interesting tutorial here (see the section **Developing a .NET application in Java**):

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Tutorial

And the main IKVM website is at **[ikvm.net](http://www.ikvm.net/index.html)**